# Is there some way to get rid of the ugly duplicate mentions of complicated variables in PHP?

Tags: php

I often encounter situations like this:

```
function stuff()
{
    $feed_data = blablabla(...);

    if ($feed_data && isset($feed_data['posts'][0]['title']))
        return $feed_data['posts'][0]['title'];

    return false;
}
```

As you can see, $feed_data['posts'][0]['title'] is returned, but it's first checked with isset() to make sure it actually exists, which is not guaranteed.

If I do not include the isset() check, it can log even uglier errors about how it doesn't exist. (When things go wrong.)

Now I'm wondering if there is some way to only have to have one instance of the reference sting `$feed_data['posts'][0]['title']` in my code, yet also do the check.

This is the most obvious "solution" which I've naturally tested:

```
$a = $feed_data['posts'][0]['title'];

if ($feed_data && isset($a))
    return $a;
```

However, this will log the error at the first line, because you cannot assign a variable which doesn't exist!

I don't see a way around this, and it's been bothering me for a long time. I hate having duplicate code snippets like that in my code.

It seems like there ought to be a better way.

Comment: One way could be the use of conditional operator to assign the value a. Would be a short one liner. You would then have to check in your if statemenet depending on what value you assign if isset returns false. But if that is a better way? i dont know

Comment: FYI, the `$feed_data && ` part is redundant anyway.

Comment: can you please tell me what data is not available is this array [0] , posts field or only title field. What is actually missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#PHP):

```
$a = $feed_data['posts'][0]['title'] ?? false;
```

It checks against having a null value, if it does, return false, else return the long variable :)

Note that this was introduced with PHP 7, you can read more [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)

Comment: `??` should be noted that that is exclusive to PHP 7+

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner If you are using php <= 7.1 you have a lot more problems than a missing operator - end of life for both 5.6 and 7.0 was january 2019. Edit: and 7.1s EOL is 1.12.2019 - so make that 7.2 :)

Comment: That too @TomRegner

Answer (score 2):

If you're specifically looking for `$feed_data['posts'][0]['title']` then you don't need to check for *both* this value and the "parent" `$feed_data` array. Simply check only for this value, as one can not exist without the other.

As [mentioned by treyBake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091078/3536236) you can use the `??` operator (PHP 7+) to place the value in the `if` statement, when the checks the value as to if the `if` is executed.

Combining these two points gives:

```
if($a = $feed_data['posts'][0]['title'] ?? false){
    // Do stuff wth $a
    return $a;
}
```

## Pre PHP 7:

*c'mon, update your system `;-)`*

**NOTE:** The result `$a` needs to be **hard checked** against false so that falsey values such as `0` or empty strings are not erroneously skipped (If you *DO* want to skip these falsey things; use `empty` instead of `isset`).

```
    if(
      ($a = isset($feed_data['posts'][0]['title']) ? 
       $feed_data['posts'][0]['title'] : false) !== false) {
          //do stuff with $a
          return $a;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you would use the `if` - surely `return $feed_data['posts'][0]['title'] ?? false;` would be more concise.

Comment: The question was about the `IF` statement, I'm sure the OPs functions will be more complex than a simple return statement.